# What should I do when "An error has occurred" when downloading Lion?

Tags: macos, upgrade, mac-appstore

I'm trying to download the new Mac OS. When click install, the icon pops onto the dock and says Waiting...

After about 5 minutes, it disappears and in the purchased category of the Mac App Store, next to install it says:

> An error has occurred

Why is this happening?

**Edit:** 
Originally I could not even get the download bar in the purchased section until I reconfigured my router slightly(I'm using a BT Business Hub). I am now able to get the download bar. However, I still get "Waiting..." on the icon and after about 3 minutes, I receive the same error message:

> An error has occurred

I still believe that it is a router problem and not the app stores' servers. Has another been able to fix this yet?

Here is a screenshot when I click the install button:
[image: A screenshot of when I click the install button]

And here is a screenshot after about 2 minutes:
[image: A screenshot after about 2 minutes]

Comment: You won't be able to pinpoint the problem until you try to download the OS from another connection/router configuration. Until then, we cannot safely say if it's Apple's servers (doesn't seem like it if it times out so readily) or your router configuration...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have sorted the issue. I just had to use a different router. The BT Business hub that I previously been using had a problem on it which prevented anything above 2GB do loose connection. This would explain other problems as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar event.  I was able to solve the problem by:

1. Signing out the app store
2. Closing app store
3. Clearing cookies in safari (evidently app store uses safari's cookies)
4. Reopen app store
5. Sign-in to the App Store
6. Press Option and click Purchases
7. Click Resume on OS X Mountain Lion under Other Purchases

Maybe this will help?

Comment: Awesome man. Its working perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

Because a lot of Mac users are probably doing the same download now. It's probably overloaded. After all 4 GB is a good bit bigger than an iTunes song or an iOS app.

Comment: That might the problem so I will wait a few hours then. If this still occurs I will report back.

Comment: It seems that it is not servers being overloaded and something else(most probably my router).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have downloaded all the latest system updates - there is one which will prepare the mac app store for lion. I had the same problem and it seems to be working now!

Comment: I have tried this and it has not helped at all, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Run Console to check the recent logs for more details (look for com.apple.installd).

In example, I had something like:

```
com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.installd[69518]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
ReportCrash[69520]: Saved crash report for installd[69518] version 332 to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/installd_2014*.crash
```

If you see the crash in your logs, then check the backtrace under System Diagnostic Reports, so there is something like:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive
```

The reason for that could be that some of the downloaded files are corrupted.

So to solve that, you have to remove these files and try again.

---

**Simple solution**

1. Quit your App Store
2. Run Finder.
3. Go to (CMD+Shift+G): /private/var/folders.
4. Trash all the folders from that folder (e.g. vp, zz).
5. Run App Store and re-try.

In case something bad happens, restore these removed files from your Trash.

---

**Advanced solution**

From Terminal check if you've temporary files here:

```
ls -la /private/var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.appstore
```

And then try to remove them (you may backup them first just in case):

```
rm -frv /private/var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.appstore
```

And re-try again.

---

Related:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4483444
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4234582

Comment: Rather than pasting this in several places - would you be open to asking a brief question "How do I troubleshoot a failed download from the Mac App store?" and then posting this in one place?

Comment: I've pasted it only 2 times as I didn't know which one was more popular and it was related to the issue. Normally one should be marked as duplicate of another one. I had similar problem and simply couldn't find any proper solution, so more avability to the clear solutions then better. Sorry about it.

Comment: It's all good - just that the system lets us know when dupes are posted. Welcome and thanks for the great posts so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved my problem by going to `/private/tmp` (similar to kenord's answer) and trashing all the `launch*` directories.

In retrospect, I think maybe I only needed to remove a launchd-*xxxx*.*yyyyyy* folder, which had a red mark on the folder icon.